# Subtables using r+hmisc

Tags: tables, positioning, subfloats

I'm not absolutly sure if it is the right place to ask my question.

I use [R+knitr](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/knitr/index.html) to produce a weekly report(s) from a large database. For my tables I find very convenient to use [hmisc](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Hmisc/index.html)'s `latex` command.

I would like to know if it is possible to arrange two tables side by side using the `latex` function from `hmisc`. I understand the LaTeX commands to do it, but the issue is that `hmisc` creates those commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution, so better share it.
It was quite simple, we just have to use the `table.env = FALSE` option of latex command of Hmisc like this:

```
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{big table caption}
   \begin{subtable}{.5\textwidth}
   \centering
<<R code to do  t table,echo=FALSE, results='asis'>>=
latex(t, file = "",table.env = FALSE,label="tab:t_table")
@
   \caption{sub table caption}
   \end{subtable}% 
   \begin{subtable}{.5\textwidth}
   \centering
<<R code to do table r,echo=FALSE, results='asis'>>=
latex(r, file = "",table.env = FALSE,label="tab:r_table")
@
   \caption{subtable caption}
   \end{subtable}
\end{table}
```

the % sign after the first `\end{subtable}` allows the 2 tables to be in the same line.